# WordPress while loop with aphabetic counting like one, two, three

Tags: php, loop

I have a question. This is my loop:

```
<?php

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'homepage_section', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

<?php 

if( !isset( $row_num ) ) $row_num = 1; // at first $row_num does not exist so create it and make uneven (start with 1)
  $row_class = (++$row_num % 2) ? 'right' : 'left'; // then check whether $row_num is odd or even and assign it the corresponding class name

  ;?>

<!-- One -->
<section id="one" class="main style2 dark fullscreen <?php echo $row_class;?>" style="background: url(<?php
        $varable_holding_img_url = the_post_thumbnail_url('full');
         echo $varable_holding_img_url; ?>);">
            <div class="content box style2">
                <header>
                    <h2><?php echo  the_title();?></h2>
                </header>
                <p><?php echo  the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <a href="#two" class="button style2 down anchored">Next</a>
        </section>

 <?php
endwhile;

    ?>
```

There is an `href` in the bottom, and I want to make `href = "#one,two,three"` dynamically change. Can anyone help me?

Comment: 'Dynamically change' can mean anything, even random assignment. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, Suppose there is a while loop. and the div is
<div id="one">.

I want to change the id dynamically like, <div id="one">, <div id="two">, <div id="three">

How is it possible using php